# Adding check for count of characters to regex expression

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression:

```
"^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\\w_-]*[\\S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\\S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\\S]$
```

(from Java).

And I want to add a check for count of characters entered and I am doing it by adding {5,15} before the ending $:

```
"^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\\w_-]*[\\S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\\S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\\S]{5,15}$"
```

but it does not work.

Could you please help me by explaining what is wrong?

Comment: what u exact want to match?? i think u r not writing `()` on right place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your change just checks whether there are 5 to 15 non-space characters in *that specific option*.

I think the usual way would be to prepend

```
(?=^.{5,15}$)
```

and put the rest in another group after that.